# How to go about scraping and writing a script for an Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, scraper

My manager has asked me to write a program that pulls data from a database that I have access to (it's an Oracle database and I'm using SQL developer). The idea is to get the data they want and put into an excel sheet in a way they would like. I haven't really wrote scripts before nor have I ever wrote a scraper, I was wondering what the first step is here and what resources I should use to get started? I have a couple of weeks to do this but I don't really know where to start.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take some time to read [ask].  This questions is way too broad.

Comment: you don't need a scraper just a plain ODBC connection to the excel file.

Comment: pro tip: if you haven't tried anything and don't know where to start, just ask nicely if anyone can give you a lead.

Comment: I would but the company isn't exactly a tech company! It's an EE internship and they don't really know where to start either, kind of on my own. But I'll look into that thanks!

Comment: How much programming experience do you have?

Comment: I've done a lot of C, C++ and Java. Made space invaders on C on an embedded system, wrote drivers etc. Basically CS course work up to Junior year of college.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with an SQL query to find the data your manager wants. If you got the right result on screen, just right-click into the query result, select 'Export', and format= Excel...